# 305 Use Proxy - Implementation by Modern Browsers

Tags: apache, http

I'm curious how the 305 Use Proxy HTTP Response Header is implemented by the latest web browsers.

What I'm hoping to accomplish is effectively as follows:

- Accept a request using Apache
- Provide a response to the browser which will indicate it should make
  the request again, on another port and/or hostname for the server
- Fork and detach the original request
- Listen on the port indicated to the browser, and handle the HTTP
  request in full by the child process

It would only be effective for my purposes if the browser does not indicate to the user the request is now being server by the child process, for this reason, 301/302 won't be effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/76

Comment: So I take it then this was never re-implemented?

Comment: My understanding is that nobody implements this.